# OIDC identity provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, openid-connect, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

We would like to integrate Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) with AWS EKS Identity Provider Configuration using OIDC.

Currently, I am not sure about Terraform AWS provider module does have the feature of OIDC integration with Azure AD directly.

I am looking similar configure of terraform AWS provider module.

For example:

```
oidc {
client_id = “spn:xxxxxxxxxxxx”
groups_claim = “xxx”
groups_prefix = “aad:”
identity_provider_config_name = “eks-oidc”
issuer_url = “xxxxxx”
username_claim = “xxx”
username_prefix = “aad:”
}
```

The above configuration template getting from the below link for a different provider.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/atlantis-eeveebank/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_identity_provider_config

how can I achieve this through terraform?
Is it the only way to configure the OIDC identity provider to our cluster using eksctl?

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/authenticate-oidc-identity-provider.html

Regards,
Nataraj.R

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is supported via Cognito?

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/introducing-oidc-identity-provider-authentication-amazon-eks/

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_identity_provider

Might be worth having a look around there and seeing if that meets your needs.

Ian.

Comment: I have another idea to accomplish this task, If I include the below yaml template into terraform, My job will be easy. 

https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/eks/latest/userguide/authenticate-oidc-identity-provider.html

Comment: I don't want to use cognito in my current scenario. Because I achieved by yaml itself